# apache permission error

Tags: linux, apache

I have centos in VMware and hosted a web application.
This is the url I try to access my page. There is also another demo page "demo.php" that I create for test. its fine can access and prints contents: "its ok." but when I try to my app page which in same directory the browser says:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /WP/View/Home/localobjects.php on this server. 

http://192.168.118.129/WP/View/Home/localobjects.php
```

How can I fix this?

Files Permissions in directory.

```
-rw-r--rwx. 1 root root  272 Apr  2 00:49 activedirectoryusers.php
-rw-r--rwx. 1 root root  236 Apr 17 01:22 configuration.php
-rw-r--rwx. 1 root root  324 Mar 30 00:59 dashboard.php
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  107 Apr 15 08:28 deneme.php
drwxr-xrwx. 2 root root 4096 Apr 17 01:22 Ipageimplementations
-rw-r--rwx. 1 root root  257 Apr 17 00:52 localobjects.php
-rw-r--rwx. 1 root root  224 Mar 28 18:41 policy.php
-rw-r--rwx. 1 root root  257 Apr 13 01:58 timeintervals.php
```

Comment: Which permissions do you have on your file? It must be "readable by everybody" (something like -rw-r--r-- when you make a `ls -l` of the folder).

Comment: @MarcoBernardini they comment down lol. I cant understand how some people become so inconsiderate. Anyway this is the output: "drwxr-xr-x. 10 root root 4096 Apr 17 00:34 WP" WP is the parent folder name of app

Comment: Permissions "drwxr-x-r-x" (directory - read/write/execute for the owner, read/execute for the group, read/execute for the group) for the folder are good. You must check the single files.

Comment: @MarcoBernardini I edited question. But there is other parent directorys and files in. is there any solution update all of them at once and fix it easy?

Comment: Your configuration is very unsafe. PHP files are writeable and executable by everybody. Mine are just "-rw-r--r--" (mode 644). You can fix that with a `chmod 644 *php`.

Comment: @MarcoBernardini I did. but still same message when I request page remotel.  permission denied..

Comment: See if all the directories above that have the right permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a cheatsheet…

Directories must have the permissions "drwxr-xr-x".

You set them with `chmod 755 [directory name]`.

Files must have the permissions "-rw-r--r--".

You set them with `chmod 644 *php` for all the php files in a folder. If you have other files which must be seen on the web (.css, etc.) chmod them accordingly.

To get the "magic numbers" you have three digits:

- the first one is for the owner
- the second one is for the owner's group
- the third is for the rest of the world

Numbers are the sum of:

- 4: readable
- 2: writeable
- 1: executable

In doubt, make a directory at a time: if you give wrong permissions (not executable, like files) to a folder you can't browse it.